# How to contour irregular point data for overlay on Google maps?

Tags: google-maps, contour

I am having some serious trouble finding a solution to fit my current needs.  I am attempting to create contour maps from irregularly spaced point-data on the fly to overlay on a Google map.  I have looked at almost everything I can find, but I haven't come across anything that seemed to do this.  I cannot generate the contours before use, as there are literally thousands of possible maps, and they change regularly.  If anyone knows of anything that might help me accomplish this, it would be extremely helpful.

EDIT: I am fairly new to all of this stuff, so there is a good chance I have missed something basic.  Please let me know if that is the case.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you capable of generating the contours yourself, or do you need guidance on this as well? How often does data change? Some weather bureau did this in the UK a while ago, but I'm having a hard time finding the info.

Comment: I don't know how to generate them myself, but I have no problem with learning to if needed- I just need to be pointed in the right direction.  The data can change at 15 minute intervals, but realistically it will only be altered over the course of a few days once or twice a year- I am working at mapping yield data collected by grain harvesters in the field.

Comment: In what sense are these maps really "dynamic"? Sure, they cover the same circle each time, but don't you generate exactly one map per harvest, from a harvest-specific collection of locations? As such, each new map has little to do with the previous one.  A truly dynamic map, on the other hand, might retain the same sample points but change their values.  The distinction is crucial, because one can set up an extremely efficient contouring algorithm in advance based on the point locations only, and then just plug in the values as they are received.

Comment: @Crash See if [gheat](http://code.google.com/p/gheat/) is what you're after.

Comment: @whuber you're right, this isn't dynamic- I didn't really understand the distinction.

Comment: @Geoist, from what I can tell a heat map isn't going to work here.  The heat maps I have used have to be tailored specifically to the data- if the radius of influence of individual data points is not properly configured, the map is more or less unusable, which also makes zoom an issue.  I spent some time trying to find a correlation between sample-count/frequency/radius, but no luck.  It also doesn't provide a meaningful scale to indicate correspondence between colors and values, and they seem to use density rather than interpolated data points, which is an issue with irregularly-spaced data.

Comment: @Crash The method for deriving contours is the same as that for a heat map.  It appears that you may be confused about what you want given your' 'newness' to this subject matter.  It seems to me, however, that this question might be better focused on the processing of the data' rather than the display?

Comment: @Geoist I guess what I am really HOPING for (admittedly it may be just a fantasy) is some sort of mapping system that can interpolate my data and make assumptions about what areas belong should be considered to have which data range, as opposed to seeing a data point as a concentration of individual points.  I know it's unlikely for me to find such a simple solution, but that's what I'm hoping for